# enter 2 arguments into a void function

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!!

I want to make a function that has two vectors as arguments like this:

geometry_msgs::Point point;
geoemtry_msgs::Point posac;
geoemtry_msgs::Point suma;

void make_suma ( const geometry_msgs::Point& point, const geometry_msgs::Point& posac)

{

suma.x=point.x + posac.x;

suma.y=point.y + posac.y;

suma.z=point.z + posac.z;

}

I get the following error when i compile it.

/home/usuario/catkin_ws/src/prueba/firmware/p1.cpp:33:60: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(const geometry_msgs::Point&, const geometry_msgs::Point&)’ to ‘ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point>::CallbackT {aka void (*)(const geometry_msgs::Point&)}’ [-fpermissive]

ros::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point> sub("operacion", make_suma);

In file included from /home/usuario/catkin_ws/build/prueba/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:84:0,

from /home/usuario/catkin_ws/build/prueba/ros_lib/ros.h:38,

from /home/usuario/catkin_ws/src/prueba/firmware/p1.cpp:8:

/home/usuario/catkin_ws/build/prueba/ros_lib/ros/subscriber.h:65:7: error: initializing argument 2 of ‘ros::Subscriber::Subscriber(const char*, ros::Subscriber::CallbackT, int) [with MsgT = geometry_msgs::Point; ros::Subscriber::CallbackT = void (*)(const geometry_msgs::Point&)]’ [-fpermissive]

Subscriber(const char * topic_name, CallbackT cb, int endpoint=rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo::ID_SUBSCRIBER) :

make[7]: *** [CMakeFiles/p1.dir/p1.cpp.obj] Error 1

make[6]: *** [CMakeFiles/p1.dir/all] Error 2

make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/p1.dir/rule] Error 2

make[4]: *** [p1] Error 2

make[3]: *** [prueba/CMakeFiles/prueba_firmware_p1] Error 2

make[2]: *** [prueba/CMakeFiles/prueba_firmware_p1.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** [prueba/CMakeFiles/prueba_firmware_p1.dir/rule] Error 2

make: *** [prueba_firmware_p1] Error 2

Invoking "make prueba_firmware_p1 -j4 -l4" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216066/enter-2-arguments-into-a-void-function/) by [Emilio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23551/emilio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to provide more of your code. However, it appears to me that you misunderstand subscriptions.

That is, a *topic* is associated with a particular type of *message*; for instance, a `geometry_msgs::Point`. The *callback* for a particular *subscriber* processes the specified type of message declared when the subscriber is instantiated (through a `NodeHandle`). Typically, the code looks like this:

```
// this is NOT valid code!!! (e.g., no main()!)
ros::Subscriber m_sub;
ros::NodeHandle nh;
...
void pointCallback(const geometry_msgs::Point &point) {
   // do something with point message
}
...
// topic: /some_point, message type: geometry_msgs::Point
// queue size: 1, callback method: pointCallback
m_sub = nh.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Point>("/some_point", 1, &pointCallback);
...
// begin processing messages
ros::spin();
```

It appears that you want to process two `Point`s on one topic. ROS doesn't work that way.

You have multiple solutions, though. You could:

- Create two subscribers (each with a callback) and process the points as you receive them (you likely want to synchronize them)
- Look into the [Message Filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) package (likely, `ApproximateTime`)
- Create a publisher for a new message type containing both `Point`s (left as an exercise for the poster)
- Some other solution

If that doesn't help, again: post more of your code so that what you are attempting is (more) clear.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0